# Natbib: cite in text with first name or initial

Tags: bibtex, natbib

One of my references is J. Doe (1999). In the `bib` file it might looks like this:

```
@article{doe-1999,
 author="John Doe",
 title="Some Paper",
 journal="Some Journal",
 volume=1, number=1, pages={1--10}, year=1999}
```

My preamble looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Hyperlinks bib references.
\begin{document}
  Please see \cite{doe-1999}.
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

In the text, I normally cite it using `\cite{doe-1999}` and that's great. But there's one spot in my document where I'd like to include Doe's first initial (or his first name if I include it in the bib). I'm using `natbib`/`plainnat` author-year style. Is there a command that would help me get "J. Doe (1999)" or "John Doe (1999)" in the text and still have the whole thing hyperlinked by way of `hyperref`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My question isn't about a problem that occurs with a certain combination of documentclass and packages. I'm just asking for a command that would let me cite references in the text with the author's first and last name using natbib.

Comment: While this can be independent of a particular class, providing example code to play with is the best way you can help who wants to help you.

Comment: 1. What should be shown when there are more than two authors of a reference? All author with their initials/first names? 2. Would it be enough when the long form you can get via `\citet*{}` will show the first names?

Comment: @mafp 1. My use for this feature is for references with a single author but I would say that when there are several authors, it would be best to show all first names. 2. Yes I think that would be exactly what I asked.

Comment: I have entered an answer for a related question in [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169424/authors-full-first-name-with-citation-in-text-citet-directives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it for a few cases, a simpler solution is to define an alias and use `\citealias`.

For your example, in the preamble, define:

```
\defcitealias{smith13}{Waldo Smith (2013)}
```

And in the text use:

```
\citetalias{smith13}
```

The result will be Waldo Smith (2013) in the text, with the reference added in the same way as the other references. If you use `\citet{smith13}`, you return to the usual Smith (2013).

The command `\citetalias` is available with the package natbib. So, you have to include `\usepackage{natbib}` in the preamble.

Note: this question is related to [Author's full first name with citation-in-text (citet{} directives)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169424/authors-full-first-name-with-citation-in-text-citet-directives)

Answer (score 4):

With the standard `natbib` styles, the `\citet*{...}` and `\citep*{...}` commands give complete author lists as opposed to the possibly abbreviated author lists that are obtained with `\citet{...}` and `\citep{...}`. We will modify this long author list to also contain first names.

1. Make a copy of `plainnat.bst`, say `plainnat2.bst`, and put it in a place where BibTeX can find it.
2. Open the copy in an editor, and locate the function `format.full.names`. It should be at line 306. Change the line

   ```
   "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
   ```

   into

   ```
   "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=   %% added {ff~}
   ```
3. Save and close it.

Use it as normal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Short form: \citet{Ca04}, \citet{MeGa05}, \citet{MaGaJoGoAsFrFr00}.

\medskip
Long form: \citet*{Ca04}, \citet*{MeGa05}, \citet*{MaGaJoGoAsFrFr00}.

% \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat2}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]